# Select count(*) gives zero on "large" result sets

Tags: mysql, select, count, innodb, mysql-5.6

I have quite a wide (many columns) table with some 400,000 rows in it, InnoDb, UTF8MB4_Unicode, some 60 columns and 11 indexes.

See definition below.

When I do a `SELECT count(*) FROM table_name WHERE user_id = X` it gives correct count only for users that doesn't have that many rows in the table.

If I do **RECREATE + ANALYZE** i.e. what MySQL does when you perform `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on an InnoDb table, it works fine the count shows correct values, until we insert new rows in the table again, and then the count is off.

Am I missing some "common knowledge" about SELECT count here or is this a bug in the latest MySQL release or is it due to my table having a lot of indexes or.... something else. I've never come across this before upgrading to 5.6.25.

I should mention that **my.cnf** only has 128 Mb InnoDb_Pool_Buffer which is probably under dimensioned for a db of this size (not huge but some 300mb gzipped from a mysqldump).

Thank you very much for taking the time to answer.

**EDIT** Adding the ouput from mysqltuner.pl -- I really appreciate any help from you guys in interpreting it (I have only Innodb tables, no MyISAM). Notice how it says I have 44 fragmented tables, but I just recently did a recreate + analyze on them. Is this due to other parameters being set too low? Thanks again.

*Removed Mysql Tuner output to give place for more relevant figures.*

Table definition (anonymized):

*Removed Table Definition since not relevant any longer*

**EDIT2** As requested, providing output from SHOW GLOBAL STATUS and SHOW VARIABLES

```
Aborted_clients 0
Aborted_connects    5
Binlog_cache_disk_use   0
Binlog_cache_use    0
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use  0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use   0
Bytes_received  1392447055
Bytes_sent  20991720246
Com_admin_commands  1739
Com_assign_to_keycache  0
Com_alter_db    0
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
Com_alter_event 0
Com_alter_function  0
Com_alter_procedure 0
Com_alter_server    0
Com_alter_table 10
Com_alter_tablespace    0
Com_alter_user  0
Com_analyze 0
Com_begin   0
Com_binlog  0
Com_call_procedure  1
Com_change_db   1567913
Com_change_master   0
Com_check   0
Com_checksum    0
Com_commit  0
Com_create_db   0
Com_create_event    0
Com_create_function 0
Com_create_index    0
Com_create_procedure    1
Com_create_server   0
Com_create_table    2
Com_create_trigger  0
Com_create_udf  0
Com_create_user 0
Com_create_view 0
Com_dealloc_sql 0
Com_delete  7717
Com_delete_multi    0
Com_do  0
Com_drop_db 0
Com_drop_event  0
Com_drop_function   0
Com_drop_index  0
Com_drop_procedure  2
Com_drop_server 0
Com_drop_table  2
Com_drop_trigger    0
Com_drop_user   0
Com_drop_view   0
Com_empty_query 0
Com_execute_sql 0
Com_flush   0
Com_get_diagnostics 0
Com_grant   0
Com_ha_close    0
Com_ha_open 0
Com_ha_read 0
Com_help    0
Com_insert  169112
Com_insert_select   37
Com_install_plugin  0
Com_kill    0
Com_load    0
Com_lock_tables 6
Com_optimize    0
Com_preload_keys    0
Com_prepare_sql 0
Com_purge   0
Com_purge_before_date   0
Com_release_savepoint   0
Com_rename_table    0
Com_rename_user 0
Com_repair  0
Com_replace 0
Com_replace_select  0
Com_reset   0
Com_resignal    0
Com_revoke  0
Com_revoke_all  0
Com_rollback    0
Com_rollback_to_savepoint   0
Com_savepoint   0
Com_select  5721646
Com_set_option  3032
Com_signal  0
Com_show_binlog_events  0
Com_show_binlogs    0
Com_show_charsets   0
Com_show_collations 35
Com_show_create_db  86
Com_show_create_event   0
Com_show_create_func    0
Com_show_create_proc    0
Com_show_create_table   587
Com_show_create_trigger 0
Com_show_databases  3
Com_show_engine_logs    0
Com_show_engine_mutex   0
Com_show_engine_status  0
Com_show_events 18
Com_show_errors 0
Com_show_fields 600
Com_show_function_code  0
Com_show_function_status    0
Com_show_grants 0
Com_show_keys   88
Com_show_master_status  0
Com_show_open_tables    0
Com_show_plugins    0
Com_show_privileges 0
Com_show_procedure_code 0
Com_show_procedure_status   0
Com_show_processlist    0
Com_show_profile    0
Com_show_profiles   0
Com_show_relaylog_events    0
Com_show_slave_hosts    0
Com_show_slave_status   0
Com_show_status 1843
Com_show_storage_engines    3
Com_show_table_status   589
Com_show_tables 6
Com_show_triggers   533
Com_show_variables  1956
Com_show_warnings   0
Com_slave_start 0
Com_slave_stop  0
Com_stmt_close  0
Com_stmt_execute    0
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    0
Com_stmt_reprepare  0
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
Com_truncate    36
Com_uninstall_plugin    0
Com_unlock_tables   6
Com_update  640052
Com_update_multi    0
Com_xa_commit   0
Com_xa_end  0
Com_xa_prepare  0
Com_xa_recover  0
Com_xa_rollback 0
Com_xa_start    0
Compression OFF
Connection_errors_accept    0
Connection_errors_internal  0
Connection_errors_max_connections   0
Connection_errors_peer_address  0
Connection_errors_select    0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap   0
Connections 1567347
Created_tmp_disk_tables 247145
Created_tmp_files   20174
Created_tmp_tables  386918
Delayed_errors  0
Delayed_insert_threads  0
Delayed_writes  0
Flush_commands  1
Handler_commit  6537068
Handler_delete  33452
Handler_discover    0
Handler_external_lock   20879224
Handler_mrr_init    0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first  1751492
Handler_read_key    5384829832
Handler_read_last   211053
Handler_read_next   19630786637
Handler_read_prev   6110703982
Handler_read_rnd    73007565
Handler_read_rnd_next   11782800964
Handler_rollback    477
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  3632409114
Handler_write   20236858098
Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status  not started
Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status  not started
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   45561
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data   746471424
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  10
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty  163840
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    2075723
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   1024
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   4614
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  51199
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   337427
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   4272
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    50351166042
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    2496152
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   25099776
Innodb_data_fsyncs  680776
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  0
Innodb_data_pending_reads   0
Innodb_data_pending_writes  0
Innodb_data_read    46916046848
Innodb_data_reads   2863706
Innodb_data_writes  3201512
Innodb_data_written 69819479040
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  2075723
Innodb_dblwr_writes 103028
Innodb_have_atomic_builtins ON
Innodb_log_waits    0
Innodb_log_write_requests   3054739
Innodb_log_writes   914722
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    244890
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
Innodb_os_log_written   1752017408
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    59717
Innodb_pages_read   2863523
Innodb_pages_written    2075723
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
Innodb_row_lock_time    7419
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    390
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    1422
Innodb_row_lock_waits   19
Innodb_rows_deleted 33451
Innodb_rows_inserted    5432696
Innodb_rows_read    29436124622
Innodb_rows_updated 596060
Innodb_num_open_files   118
Innodb_truncated_status_writes  0
Innodb_available_undo_logs  128
Key_blocks_not_flushed  0
Key_blocks_unused   6698
Key_blocks_used 6698
Key_read_requests   45635462325
Key_reads   6589434
Key_write_requests  12131142501
Key_writes  9617220
Last_query_cost 0.000000
Last_query_partial_plans    0
Max_used_connections    17
Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0
Open_files  46
Open_streams    0
Open_table_definitions  166
Open_tables 287
Opened_files    1009110
Opened_table_definitions    226
Opened_tables   397
Performance_schema_accounts_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_digest_lost  0
Performance_schema_file_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_handles_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_hosts_lost   0
Performance_schema_locker_lost  0
Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost   0
Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_handles_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_users_lost   0
Prepared_stmt_count 0
Qcache_free_blocks  1
Qcache_free_memory  1031352
Qcache_hits 0
Qcache_inserts  0
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   5720393
Qcache_queries_in_cache 0
Qcache_total_blocks 1
Queries 9771703
Questions   9640606
Select_full_join    4608
Select_full_range_join  0
Select_range    385947
Select_range_check  0
Select_scan 1745605
Slave_heartbeat_period   
Slave_last_heartbeat     
Slave_open_temp_tables  0
Slave_received_heartbeats    
Slave_retried_transactions   
Slave_running   OFF
Slow_launch_threads 0
Slow_queries    16
Sort_merge_passes   17244
Sort_range  214894
Sort_rows   199889850
Sort_scan   260475
Ssl_accept_renegotiates 0
Ssl_accepts 0
Ssl_callback_cache_hits 0
Ssl_cipher   
Ssl_cipher_list  
Ssl_client_connects 0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_depth    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_mode 0
Ssl_default_timeout 0
Ssl_finished_accepts    0
Ssl_finished_connects   0
Ssl_server_not_after     
Ssl_server_not_before    
Ssl_session_cache_hits  0
Ssl_session_cache_misses    0
Ssl_session_cache_mode  NONE
Ssl_session_cache_overflows 0
Ssl_session_cache_size  0
Ssl_session_cache_timeouts  0
Ssl_sessions_reused 0
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries  0
Ssl_verify_depth    0
Ssl_verify_mode 0
Ssl_version  
Table_locks_immediate   10362193
Table_locks_waited  49
Table_open_cache_hits   10367123
Table_open_cache_misses 396
Table_open_cache_overflows  0
Tc_log_max_pages_used   0
Tc_log_page_size    0
Tc_log_page_waits   0
Threads_cached  7
Threads_connected   3
Threads_created 30
Threads_running 1
Uptime  520269
Uptime_since_flush_status   520269
```

Show Variables

```
auto_increment_increment    1
auto_increment_offset   1
autocommit  ON
automatic_sp_privileges ON
avoid_temporal_upgrade  OFF
back_log    80
basedir /usr
big_tables  OFF
bind_address    127.0.0.1
binlog_cache_size   32768
binlog_checksum CRC32
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates OFF
binlog_error_action IGNORE_ERROR
binlog_format   STATEMENT
binlog_gtid_simple_recovery OFF
binlog_max_flush_queue_time 0
binlog_order_commits    ON
binlog_row_image    FULL
binlog_rows_query_log_events    OFF
binlog_stmt_cache_size  32768
binlogging_impossible_mode  IGNORE_ERROR
block_encryption_mode   aes-128-ecb
bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608
character_set_client    utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database  utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8mb4
character_set_server    utf8mb4
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
collation_connection    utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_database  utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server    utf8mb4_unicode_ci
completion_type NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert   AUTO
connect_timeout 10
core_file   OFF
datadir /var/lib/mysql/
date_format %Y-%m-%d
datetime_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
default_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_tmp_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_week_format 0
delay_key_write ON
delayed_insert_limit    100
delayed_insert_timeout  300
delayed_queue_size  1000
disconnect_on_expired_password  ON
div_precision_increment 4
end_markers_in_json OFF
enforce_gtid_consistency    OFF
eq_range_index_dive_limit   10
error_count 0
event_scheduler OFF
expire_logs_days    0
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp ON
external_user    
flush   OFF
flush_time  0
foreign_key_checks  ON
ft_boolean_syntax   + -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len 84
ft_min_word_len 4
ft_query_expansion_limit    20
ft_stopword_file    (built-in)
general_log OFF
general_log_file    /var/lib/mysql/prouction.log
group_concat_max_len    1024
gtid_executed    
gtid_mode   OFF
gtid_next   AUTOMATIC
gtid_owned   
gtid_purged  
have_compress   YES
have_crypt  YES
have_dynamic_loading    YES
have_geometry   YES
have_openssl    DISABLED
have_profiling  YES
have_query_cache    YES
have_rtree_keys YES
have_ssl    DISABLED
have_symlink    DISABLED
host_cache_size 279
hostname    pgprod
identity    0
ignore_builtin_innodb   OFF
ignore_db_dirs   
init_connect     
init_file    
init_slave   
innodb_adaptive_flushing    ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm    10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index  ON
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay 150000
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size 8388608
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval   5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock  OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog    OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl   OFF
innodb_api_trx_level    0
innodb_autoextend_increment 64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    1
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_filename ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    8
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort   OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size 838860800
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25
innodb_change_buffering all
innodb_checksum_algorithm   innodb
innodb_checksums    ON
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled    OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency   0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct    5
innodb_compression_level    6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max  50
innodb_concurrency_tickets  5000
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir     
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache  OFF
innodb_doublewrite  ON
innodb_fast_shutdown    1
innodb_file_format  Antelope
innodb_file_format_check    ON
innodb_file_format_max  Antelope
innodb_file_per_table   ON
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  2
innodb_flush_method O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_neighbors  1
innodb_flushing_avg_loops   30
innodb_force_load_corrupted OFF
innodb_force_recovery   0
innodb_ft_aux_table  
innodb_ft_cache_size    8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword   ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size    84
innodb_ft_min_token_size    3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize 2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit    2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table  
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree   2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size  640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table    
innodb_io_capacity  200
innodb_io_capacity_max  2000
innodb_large_prefix OFF
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size  8388608
innodb_log_compressed_pages ON
innodb_log_file_size    134217728
innodb_log_files_in_group   2
innodb_log_group_home_dir   ./
innodb_lru_scan_depth   1024
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  75
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  0
innodb_max_purge_lag    0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay  0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups  1
innodb_monitor_disable   
innodb_monitor_enable    
innodb_monitor_reset     
innodb_monitor_reset_all     
innodb_old_blocks_pct   37
innodb_old_blocks_time  1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size    134217728
innodb_open_files   431
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only   OFF
innodb_page_size    16384
innodb_print_all_deadlocks  OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size 300
innodb_purge_threads    1
innodb_random_read_ahead    OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56
innodb_read_io_threads  4
innodb_read_only    OFF
innodb_replication_delay    0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
innodb_rollback_segments    128
innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay  6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc    ON
innodb_stats_method nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata    OFF
innodb_stats_persistent ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages    20
innodb_stats_sample_pages   8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages 8
innodb_status_output    OFF
innodb_status_output_locks  OFF
innodb_strict_mode  OFF
innodb_support_xa   ON
innodb_sync_array_size  1
innodb_sync_spin_loops  30
innodb_table_locks  ON
innodb_thread_concurrency   0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   10000
innodb_undo_directory   .
innodb_undo_logs    128
innodb_undo_tablespaces 0
innodb_use_native_aio   ON
innodb_use_sys_malloc   ON
innodb_version  5.6.25
innodb_write_io_threads 4
insert_id   0
interactive_timeout 28800
join_buffer_size    262144
keep_files_on_create    OFF
key_buffer_size 8388608
key_cache_age_threshold 300
key_cache_block_size    1024
key_cache_division_limit    100
large_files_support ON
large_page_size 0
large_pages OFF
last_insert_id  0
lc_messages en_US
lc_messages_dir /usr/share/mysql/
lc_time_names   en_US
license GPL
local_infile    ON
lock_wait_timeout   31536000
locked_in_memory    OFF
log_bin OFF
log_bin_basename     
log_bin_index    
log_bin_trust_function_creators OFF
log_bin_use_v1_row_events   OFF
log_error   /var/log/mysql/error.log
log_output  FILE
log_queries_not_using_indexes   OFF
log_slave_updates   OFF
log_slow_admin_statements   OFF
log_slow_slave_statements   OFF
log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes  0
log_warnings    1
long_query_time 10.000000
low_priority_updates    OFF
lower_case_file_system  OFF
lower_case_table_names  0
master_info_repository  FILE
master_verify_checksum  OFF
max_allowed_packet  4194304
max_binlog_cache_size   18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size 1073741824
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size  18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors  100
max_connections 151
max_delayed_threads 20
max_digest_length   1024
max_error_count 64
max_heap_table_size 16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads  20
max_join_size   18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data    1024
max_prepared_stmt_count 16382
max_relay_log_size  0
max_seeks_for_key   18446744073709551615
max_sort_length 1024
max_sp_recursion_depth  0
max_tmp_tables  32
max_user_connections    0
max_write_lock_count    18446744073709551615
metadata_locks_cache_size   1024
metadata_locks_hash_instances   8
min_examined_row_limit  0
multi_range_count   256
myisam_data_pointer_size    6
myisam_max_sort_file_size   9223372036853727232
myisam_mmap_size    18446744073709551615
myisam_recover_options  OFF
myisam_repair_threads   1
myisam_sort_buffer_size 8388608
myisam_stats_method nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap OFF
net_buffer_length   16384
net_read_timeout    30
net_retry_count 10
net_write_timeout   60
new OFF
old OFF
old_alter_table OFF
old_passwords   0
open_files_limit    1024
optimizer_prune_level   1
optimizer_search_depth  62
optimizer_switch    index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on
optimizer_trace enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features    greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on
optimizer_trace_limit   1
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size    16384
optimizer_trace_offset  -1
performance_schema  ON
performance_schema_accounts_size    100
performance_schema_digests_size 5000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size  1000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size   10
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size  1000
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size   10
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size   1000
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size    10
performance_schema_hosts_size   100
performance_schema_max_cond_classes 80
performance_schema_max_cond_instances   1382
performance_schema_max_file_classes 50
performance_schema_max_file_handles 32768
performance_schema_max_file_instances   2557
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes    200
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances  5755
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes   40
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances 3138
performance_schema_max_socket_classes   10
performance_schema_max_socket_instances 230
performance_schema_max_stage_classes    150
performance_schema_max_statement_classes    168
performance_schema_max_table_handles    616
performance_schema_max_table_instances  684
performance_schema_max_thread_classes   50
performance_schema_max_thread_instances 288
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size   512
performance_schema_setup_actors_size    100
performance_schema_setup_objects_size   100
performance_schema_users_size   100
pid_file    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
plugin_dir  /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/
port    3306
preload_buffer_size 32768
profiling   OFF
profiling_history_size  15
protocol_version    10
proxy_user   
pseudo_slave_mode   OFF
pseudo_thread_id    1568066
query_alloc_block_size  8192
query_cache_limit   1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit    4096
query_cache_size    1048576
query_cache_type    OFF
query_cache_wlock_invalidate    OFF
query_prealloc_size 8192
rand_seed1  0
rand_seed2  0
range_alloc_block_size  4096
read_buffer_size    131072
read_only   OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size    262144
relay_log    
relay_log_basename   
relay_log_index  
relay_log_info_file relay-log.info
relay_log_info_repository   FILE
relay_log_purge ON
relay_log_recovery  OFF
relay_log_space_limit   0
report_host  
report_password  
report_port 3306
report_user  
rpl_stop_slave_timeout  31536000
secure_auth ON
secure_file_priv     
server_id   0
server_id_bits  32
server_uuid 28674a00-1caa-11e5-8871-f23c9126e5eb
show_old_temporals  OFF
simplified_binlog_gtid_recovery OFF
skip_external_locking   ON
skip_name_resolve   OFF
skip_networking OFF
skip_show_database  OFF
slave_allow_batching    OFF
slave_checkpoint_group  512
slave_checkpoint_period 300
slave_compressed_protocol   OFF
slave_exec_mode STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir   /tmp
slave_max_allowed_packet    1073741824
slave_net_timeout   3600
slave_parallel_workers  0
slave_pending_jobs_size_max 16777216
slave_rows_search_algorithms    TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
slave_skip_errors   OFF
slave_sql_verify_checksum   ON
slave_transaction_retries   10
slave_type_conversions   
slow_launch_time    2
slow_query_log  OFF
slow_query_log_file /var/lib/mysql/pgprod-slow.log
socket  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
sort_buffer_size    262144
sql_auto_is_null    OFF
sql_big_selects ON
sql_buffer_result   OFF
sql_log_bin ON
sql_log_off OFF
sql_mode    STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql_notes   ON
sql_quote_show_create   ON
sql_safe_updates    OFF
sql_select_limit    18446744073709551615
sql_slave_skip_counter  0
sql_warnings    OFF
ssl_ca   
ssl_capath   
ssl_cert     
ssl_cipher   
ssl_crl  
ssl_crlpath  
ssl_key  
storage_engine  InnoDB
stored_program_cache    256
sync_binlog 0
sync_frm    ON
sync_master_info    10000
sync_relay_log  10000
sync_relay_log_info 10000
system_time_zone    CEST
table_definition_cache  615
table_open_cache    431
table_open_cache_instances  1
thread_cache_size   9
thread_concurrency  10
thread_handling one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack    262144
time_format %H:%i:%s
time_zone   SYSTEM
timed_mutexes   OFF
timestamp   1436434135.246666
tmp_table_size  16777216
tmpdir  /tmp
transaction_alloc_block_size    8192
transaction_allow_batching  OFF
transaction_prealloc_size   4096
tx_isolation    REPEATABLE-READ
tx_read_only    OFF
unique_checks   ON
updatable_views_with_limit  YES
version 5.6.25
version_comment MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  Linux
wait_timeout    28800
warning_count   0
```

Comment: If you give a minus vote, please grow a pair and at least comment on WHY you give it a minus.

Comment: What version did you upgrade from?  (That might help narrowing down the alleged bug.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore "fragmented" -- It is essentially never an issue with InnoDB tables.  Do not run `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.  (If you do, do `SHOW TABLE STATUS` before and after -- to see that it did not help much.)

You have 4GB of RAM?  `innodb_buffer_pool_size` could probably be raised to 600M.

QC disabled -- that's usually "good" for production systems.

`BIGINT` (8 bytes) is rarely needed, unless you expect to have more than 4 billion things (INT UNSIGNED - 4 bytes - max of 4 billion).

If you want more analysis that mysqltuner gives, provide me with `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` (after the server has been up at least a day).

Back to the main question...  I see no reason for this particular query to be wrong:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table_name WHERE user_id = X
```

If you do `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, you will see that it will use an index.  Indexes never get corrupted in InnoDB.

You suggest that 5.6.25 could have a problem.  Yes, there is always a chance of such.  (MySQL has a good reputation for not having regressions, which this certainly would be.)  Keep an eye on bugs.mysql.com.  File a bug there.  Consider downgrading.

**VARIABLES/STATUS analysis**

Not a lot to be found in the settings:

( Key_reads ) = 6,589,434 / 520269 = 13 /sec -- MyISAM index read (from disk) rate
( Key_reads + Key_writes ) = (6589434 + 9617220) / 520269 = 31 /sec -- MyISAM index I/O rate
You are using a lot of MyISAM; **`key_buffer_size`** (8M) should be increased to, say, 100M.

( Created_tmp_disk_tables / (Created_tmp_disk_tables + Created_tmp_tables) ) = 247,145 / (247145 + 386918) = 39.0% -- Percent of temp tables that spilled to disk
-- maybe increase tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size; avoid blobs, etc.
( Select_scan ) = 1,745,605 / 520269 = 3.4 /sec -- full table scans
-- Add indexes / optimize queries (unless they are tiny tables)
( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 1,745,605 / 5721646 = 30.5% -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries

( open_files_limit ) = 1,024 -- ulimit -n
-- To allow more files, change **ulimit** or /etc/security/limits.conf or in sysctl.conf (kern.maxfiles & kern.maxfilesperproc) or something else (OS dependent)

( Connections ) = 1,567,347 / 520269 = 3 /sec -- Connections
-- Increase wait_timeout; use pooling?

You have the Query Cache half-off. You should set both query_cache_type = OFF and query_cache_size = 0 . There is (according to a rumor) a 'bug' in the QC code that leaves some code on unless you turn off both of those settings.

Comment: Thanks Rick. I sincerely appreciate the help. I will provide the show variables and show global status here tomorrow and if you feel like it, please have a shot at those. Meanwhile back at the ranch, I dropped the index it was using, recreated the index using ALL columns that the where clause held, a few columns more than just the user, and bada-bing-bada-bong, now it works like clockwork. I raised the innoddb_buffer_pool size to 2GB, too much?

Comment: With only 4GB of RAM, a 2GB buffer pool is risky.  Be sure that you don't allocate so much RAM that swapping occurs.  Swapping is much worse on performance than having a smaller cache (buffer_pool).  Other apps (Java, web server, PHP, etc) also take up RAM.

Comment: At long last I've finally come around to update the question with the requested Show Variables and Show Global Status commands. The server has 4GB in RAM, and MySQL is hitting CPU limit frequently. Any insights would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: (added analysis).  Back to your "count is zero" issue -- Please provide specifics -- the actual string in question, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `EXPLAIN SELECT...`, etc.

Comment: Just a quick comment to begin with on your analysis: I'm not using any MyISAM tables. I have 85 Innodb tables. That's it. How can it be using any MyISAM still?

Comment: On the original question, when I dropped the index it was using and created a new index with _all_ columns I was using in the where clause, not just user_id, it went like clock work. So, even though you may be correct that an index can't be corrupt in innodb, it sure gave me a lot of strange results when using that particular index. So I really don't know what to do with this question. It drifted on into "optimizing MySQL" - with insights from you for which I'm very greatful so I can just go ahead and accept your answer if you will, though this question won't provide much help to others.

Comment: 6 _million_ `Key_reads` (13/sec) says you are doing a lot of MyISAM work, at least at some time since the last restart, 520K seconds (6 days) ago.  9M `Key_writes` says you are updating things, too.  (No, I can't tell what tables are involved.)

Comment: The only MyISAM tables I have are the system tables that were there when installing MySQL. Thanks still Rick. I'll set your answer as accpeted.